# overridePendingTransition() doesn't work in TimerTask

Tags: android

I want to show Activity Animation when satrtactivity  or   finish ，but  it invalid probably in TimerTask Thread(I knwon it work in UI Thread)

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                startActivity(new Intent(myActionAnimation.this,activitytest.class));
                overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.slide_in_left, android.R.anim.slide_out_right);
            }
        }, 100);
```

can anyboby explain it?    thx.

Answer (score 3):

You simply use this:

```
    Handler h = new Handler();
    h.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            startActivity(new Intent(myActionAnimation.this,
                    activitytest.class));
            myActionAnimation.this.overridePendingTransition(
                    android.R.anim.slide_in_left, android.R.anim.slide_out_right);
            finish();
        }
    }, 5000);
```

Answer (score 1):

I have also face this problem and after some research i found one solution and it is working 
You should use Handler for this like

```
  Handler handler=new Handler(){
    public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {

        startActivity(new Intent(myActionAnimation.this,
                activitytest.class));
        myActionAnimation.this.overridePendingTransition(
                android.R.anim.slide_in_left, android.R.anim.slide_out_right);
        finish();

    };
};
```

and in the thread you need to call this like

```
   Timer timer = new Timer();
   timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
          handler.sendMessage(new Message());
        }
    }, 100);
```

I think it may help you 
happy coding